# Why is action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" added into AndroidManifest.xml when there is a android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"

Tags: android, android-studio

I know I can set `<action android:name...>` in AndroidManifest.xml.

I think that `<action android:name...>` can only assigned one time.

But from the following project, I find `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>` is added into AndroidManifest.xml when there is a `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>`, why?

https://github.com/sanogueralorenzo/Android-Kotlin-Clean-Architecture

https://github.com/igorwojda/android-showcase

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sanogueralorenzo.namingishard">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        ...
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But from the following project, I find  is added into AndroidManifest.xml when there is a , why?

From [the documentation that explains this.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#Receiving)

> You can create a filter that includes more than one instance of <action>, <data>, or <category>. If you do, you need to be certain that the component can handle any and all combinations of those filter elements.

In other words, this is a shortcut to indicate that the app handles an intent that *either* has the `MAIN` action or the `VIEW` action, with the `LAUNCHER` category.

In other other words, this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The documentation also provides [an example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#ExampleFilters).

Answer (score 0):

> To enable Google to crawl your app content and allow users to enter
> your app from search results, you must add intent filters for the
> relevant activities in your app manifest. These intent filters allow
> deep linking to the content in any of your activities. For example,
> the user might click on a deep link to view a page within a shopping
> app that describes a product offering that the user is searching for.

this is the first reason and the second one is

> ACTION_VIEW
> Use this action in an intent with startActivity() when you have some information that an activity can show to the user, such as a
> photo to view in a gallery app, or an address to view in a map app.

while
The ACTION_MAIN action indicates this is the main entry point and does not expect any intent data.
so activity can have both